# Core data Fetch request on relationship properties

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

My app has a number of wordLists each of which contain a number of words. In one view controller a tableView lists the wordLists and then a sub view controller has a tableView with the words in it. The segue passes the wordList entity. But I cannot work out how to do a fetch request on the wordList passed to then get all the words. Error message is shown below. I need to do a fetch request rather than looking at properties so I can do a sort.

Thanks in advance for any help on this one....

The WordList entity has an attribute listName, and relationships: words, destination: Word, Inverse: wordList

The Word entity has an attribute wordName, wordIndex and relationships: wordList, destination: WordList, Inverse: words

My WordsViewController looks like:

```
class WordsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {

var coreDataStack: CoreDataStack = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).coreDataStack

var wordList: WordList?
var words = [Word]()
var word: Word?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set the title of the scene
    title = wordList?.listName

   // fetch all the words that are part of the wordList passed to this VC.
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Word")
    let wordListPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "word.wordList == '\(wordList)'") // GIVES AN ERROR SAYING UNABLE TO PARSE THE FORMAT STRING "word.wordList == 'Optional(<WordList:0x...

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "wordIndex", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.predicate = wordListPredicate

    do {
        if let results = try coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Word] {
            words = results
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("There was an error fetching system person")
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use string interpolation to build a predicate, use
argument substitution instead. In your case (since `var wordList: WordList?` is an
optional):

```
if let theWordlist = wordlist {
    let wordListPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "wordList == %@", theWordlist)
} else {
    // wordlist is nil ...
}
```

Note also that `"word.wordList == "` in the predicate should be
`"wordList == "`, because "wordList" is the property of the "Word"
entity.

For more information, see [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)
in the "Predicate Programming Guide".

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, not fetch all data in `viewDidLoad`. The fetched results controller will help you fetch and display the data efficiently, react to changes, optimize memory, etc.

In the fetched results controller's fetch request (which fetches entity `Word`), use this predicate (with a safeguard if your optional `wordList` is `nil`):

```
request.predicate = wordList != nil ?
  NSPredicate(format: "wordlist = %@", wordList!) :
  NSPredicate(value: false)
```

This assumes that there is a **one-to-many** relationship between word list and its words. I would recommend this setup, even if it implies that you might have to store the same word more than once if it is in different lists.

*NB: the false predicate ensures you get a valid fetch request which will fetch nothing.*

Comment: The case `wordlist == nil` could be a *programming error*, and then – in my opinion – a crash is better than "silently" displaying nothing.

Comment: True, this is perhaps also a matter of style.